# I want to download all the images of my boards on pinterest

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am now trying to download all the images on the board using selenium.

However, I am unable to log in.
How should I click on this and enter my ID:Pass?

```
<div data-test-id="login-button">
```

Comment: Please [Edit]  your post with proper HTML element or URL and code trial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-test-id='login-button']")
```

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [25], in <cell line: 6>()
      4 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
      5 driver.get(url)
----> 6 loginButton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-test-id='login-button']")
      7 loginButton.click()

NameError: name 'By' is not defined

Comment: You need to add this in imports `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`